# writing cell array into text file and managin the variables in import wizard

Tags: database, matlab

I have a cell array of matrices

```
my_cell =
[3 x 3] [3 x 3] [3 x 3]
```

after writing it to a text file with `dlmwrite`, I need to import this data to import wizard in a way that the `my_cell(1,1)` would be the first variable, `my_cell(1,2)` the second and `my_cell(1,3)` the third one.

This is my code:

```
V = [R1 k1 d1 ;R2 k2 d2 ; R3 k3 d3];
mycell = cell(1,3);
mycell{1,1} =  [R1 k1 d1 ;R2 k2 d2 ; R3 k3 d3];
mycell{1,2} = ones(3);
mycell{1,3} = zeroes(3);
mat = cell2mat(mycell);
dlmwrite('datas.txt', mat ,'precision','%.5f');
```

and the result after importing is this: 
[image]

Is there any way to make such a table as I desire?

Comment: why not simply use `mat2cell`?

Comment: can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it:

```
x = dlmread('datas.txt'); % Note that data is already plural. datum is singular!
y = mat2cell(x, 3, [3 3 3])
```

`mat2cell` does the reverse operation of `cell2mat` given the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, but how this is going to change the output in the table created by import wizard? P.S:by datas I meant dataset in a shorter way :)

Comment: why do you need to use the import wizard?

Comment: I want to put data in a text file and then use it as a database by importing it ( then the import wizard opens ) as shown in the image but not the way I need and I don't know what function must be used  to change it

Comment: what kind of database? I don't think I understand your question. You are not going to load this file into MATLAB? What is this import wizard?

Comment: No, as I mentioned in the question I want to put this data in a text file I used dlmwrite, I don't need to put it back in MATLAB.